# Xamarin.Forms Shared is not display image in Android view, but display image in iOS view

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am creating welcome screen in Xamarin shared application.Welcome screen has to show the image few seconds then navigate to login page.It is perfectly working in IOS, but not displaying image in Android.

```
 public Page()
    {


        //var beachImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
        //beachImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("nextera.png");
        Image logo = new Image { WidthRequest = 800, HeightRequest = 800 };
        logo.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("nextera.png");
        logo.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { logo },
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand

        };
        WaitAndExecute(2000);

    }

    private async Task WaitAndExecute(int milisec)
    {
        await Task.Delay(milisec);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add to the android project the file "nextera.png" to

```
Resources/drawable
```

directory with Build Action: AndroidResource

A full guide for adding an image in Xamarin - [Xamarin official guideline for loading a local image](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)

Comment: Sure.
Did you managed to display the image using these actions?

Comment: Yes but with the code in the link that you provided